# memory leaks in ios but I don't know what it means?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

[image]

I cannot get the point from the Image where the Leaks Tool show...

Comment: track the leak with memory use of the thread nothing but size in the tree.

Comment: Could you provide some more context of what you're trying to do and when in the process you are seeing this leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instrument will show the Dropdown options for Leak below the graph like Call Tree and Leaks like that.Select the one you are comfortable and in the left pane select the Leaks,it will usually show leaks along with allocations something.Hope it will help,if helped Select as correct answer by the checkmark in the left of this answer.